# Implement Recursive CTE for Hierarchical Query to MariaDB

Tags: sql, jpa, mariadb, jpa-2.0, recursive-query

I have this table which I would like to store a chain of records.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id INT,
    unique_id varchar,
    reference_id varchar,
);
```

I want to implement SQL query for MariDB which prints all records by unique_id with all record reference_id. Something like this:

```
| id | unique_id | reference_id |   |   |
|----|-----------|--------------|---|---|
| 43 | 55544     |              |   |   |
| 45 | 45454     | 43           |   |   |
| 66 | 55655     | 45           |   |   |
| 78 | 88877     | 66           |   |   |
| 99 | 454       | 33           |   |   |
```

I would like when I select record 55544 to get all transactions because each other are using id which points to them. How I can implement this using  Recursive CTE? Is there a better  way?

Expected result for record with unique_id 55544:

```
| id | unique_id | reference_id |   |   |
|----|-----------|--------------|---|---|
| 43 | 55544     |              |   |   |
| 45 | 45454     | 43           |   |   |
| 66 | 55655     | 45           |   |   |
| 78 | 88877     | 66           |   |   |
```

How this query can be implemented also in HQL? I want to use it in JPA?

Comment: I suppose that complete answer is impossible because of: `How this query can be implemented also in HQL?`. Please correct me if I wrong but HQL does not support all types CTEs and has no way to implement recursive queries. Maybe some 'clever' tricks with NamedQuery/NamedNativeQuery - IDK.

Comment: Can this query be rewritten in JPA? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54394019/1103606

Comment: You can run native SQL through JPA. Regarding JPQL - I suppose not.

Comment: You should have the same data type for `reference_id` and `id` not you have type mismatch (INT vs VARCHAR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should do what you expect. It's a recursive query that relies on a variable to follow the parent-child relationships trough the dependency tree.

```
select @ref:=id as id, unique_id, reference_id
from mytable
join (select @ref:=id from mytable WHERE unique_id = 55544)tmp
where reference_id=@ref
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jKJodfVfvw65aMaVDyFySd/0)** yields :

```
| id  | unique_id | reference_id |
| --- | --------- | ------------ |
| 45  | 45454     | 43           |
| 66  | 55655     | 45           |
| 78  | 88877     | 66           |
```

---

PS : please note that this does not return the uppermost parent row. If you need it as well, you can change the `WHERE` condition to :

```
where reference_id=@ref or unique_id = 55544
```

Comment: I need to ask addition question. How I can get all rows when I send id 66?

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work even on MySQL 5. I'm wondering though if there's a way to reverse it, and get the IDs up from 78 to 66, 45 and 43

Answer (score 8):

You can use a recursive CTE.  That is the right way to do this:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select t.*
      from table_name t
      where t.unique_id = 55544
      union all
      select t.*
      from cte join
           table_name t
           on cte.id = t.reference_id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: How I can get all records up and down with reference id? Currently I get only below records: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sMQvdieGxZA3RB548qPS68/0

Comment: @PeterPenzov  change `on cte.id = t.reference_id` to `on cte.reference_id = t.id`

Comment: This is an absolutely beautiful and super useful piece of SQL. Thank you so much, Gordon!